# Can't post on my own business time line. Error says. The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem when trying to post on my own business time line on facebook.

**I get an error that says:
"(OAuthException)(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"**

I think this has to do with the scope "publish_actions" in somehow but how can I authorize this publish_actions permission exactly?
I have looked everywhere in my account under "https://developers.facebook.com"

I have put my App for review but I cant add "publish_actions" as a permission for Facebook to review because on this permission there is a message which says: **"It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days"**

But how can I use this permission without having the permission?? 
I would be very greatful for help if I am on the right track and what I am missing out?

Thank you!

```
    try
    {
        String appID = "12345";
        String appSecret = "123456";
        String accessToken = "123|1234_a-b";
        String clientToken = "1234567";
        String pageID = "123456789";
        Facebook.FacebookClient client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);


        var dicParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dicParams["message"] = "Hello on the time line message!";
        dicParams["caption"] = string.Empty;
        dicParams["description"] = string.Empty;
        dicParams["name"] = "Some Name";
        dicParams["req_perms"] = "publish_stream,manage_pages,status_update,publish_actions";
        dicParams["scope"] = "publish_stream,manage_pages,status_update,publish_actions";
        dicParams["access_token"] = accessToken;
        var publishResponse = client.Post("/" + pageID + "/feed", dicParams);


        MessageBox.Show("You posted on the timeline successfully!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

---

Attempt 2:
I was looking at the facebook documentation and found an URL which seems relevant to post a message on the business page timeline:

**POST graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/feed?message={message}&access_token={access-token}**

I have tried to put it down in code like below but again, I receive the same error message:

**(OAuthException)(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**

Question is what I do wrong. Do I need to get any other access token with "publish_action" permission?. If that is the case I can't figure out how to get such token?

```
            String appID = "12345";
            String appSecret = "123456";
            String accessToken = "123|1234_a-b";
            String clientToken = "1234567";
            String pageID = "123456789";
            String message = "Hello World";

            String requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageID + "/feed?message=" + message + "&access_token=" + accessToken;


            RestSharp.RestClient rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
            RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

            request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;

            RestSharp.RestResponse restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
            RestSharp.ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;


            //"(OAuthException)(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
            MessageBox.Show(restResponse.Content.ToString());
```

Comment: Why are you asking for publish_stream when there is no permission named that? And you are using an app access token and not a user or page access token

Comment: you need to stop using old code from some old blogpost (i assume) and start reading the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs - and don´t just use random (and deprecated) permissions without knowing why.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Yes the code is from some post. I have red the developers.facebook.com/docs documentation for several days but I can't find a complete example of how to do it, so I ended up here in order to understand how to be able to post on the timeline.

Comment: I have tried to come up with an attempt 2 above using an URL from the facebook documentation but with the same error message? All info is avaliable in Attempt 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works. This code do post a "Message" to the timeline.

**Question** This code works for my business page. I also like to post on my personal page for friends. So tried to change the pageID to the the ID which is my personal page: (pageID = "987654321") but still it posts on my business page.

I wonder if I need to get a page token specifically for the personal page as well?
If that is the case, I wonder how this token can be achieved?

```
            /*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
            //STEPS!!! to get a non-expiring page access token:

            //1. access the following URL and note the returned access token within the browser's address bar:
            //https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=manage_pages,publish_actions&response_type=token

            //2. access the following URL and within the returned data find the desired page's name and note the access token:
            //https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_RETURNED_FROM_STEP_1

            //3. access the following URL and note the returned access token:
            //https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=PAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_STEP_2
            //use the Access Token Debugger to ensure your access token's profile ID matches the desired page's ID and it never expires

            String newaccesstoken = "aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddd";
            /*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

            String appID = "12345";
            String appSecret = "123456";
            String accessToken = "123|1234_a-b";
            String clientToken = "1234567";
            String pageID = "123456789"; //Business page
            //String pageID = "987654321"; //Personal page
            String redirectURI = "http://example.com";
            String message = "Hello Facebook";
            String imageURL = "http://example.com/images/example-image.png";
            String link = "http://example.co";
            String caption = "example";



            //Post a message to the time line
            String requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageID + "/feed?message=" + message + "&url=" + imageURL + 
                                                                                                      "&access_token=" + newaccesstoken;

            RestSharp.RestClient rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
            RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

            request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;

            RestSharp.RestResponse restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
            RestSharp.ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;

            MessageBox.Show(restResponse.Content.ToString() + "," + responseStatus.ToString());
```